# What's the name of the short song that plays at the end of goals on Neo Tokyo?

Tags: rocket-league, game-music-identification

On the Neo Tokyo map, when anyone scores a goal, it plays a short tune. Can I play that song on a media player? If so, where can I find its file?

I am playing on PC.

Comment: You should ask on Reddit and link [/u/Psyonix_SoundGuy](https://www.reddit.com/user/Psyonix_SoundGuy).  He is probably the only person who can give a definitive answer.  Also, while you're there, ask him to fix [the Japanese audio bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/4y598k/bug_neo_tokyo_japanese_audio_says_im_sorry_after/) :)

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: the files are there but they seem to be protected.

### Background music

Sound files of Rocket League have the WEM extension and are located in the directory

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketLeague\TAGame\CookedPCConsole\
```

Now of course the question is, which one of them is it? You can use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), set a filter for ".wem" and then start a Neo Tokio local game with AIs.

This will give you the name `642633853.wem`.

To play that file, you need to convert it first. [ww2ogg [Github]](https://github.com/hcs64/ww2ogg) ([direct Download](https://github.com/hcs64/ww2ogg/releases)) can extract the sound and make it an OGG file.

On my PC the conversion pretended to be successful

```
Audiokinetic Wwise RIFF/RIFX Vorbis to Ogg Vorbis converter 0.24 by hcs

Input: 642633853.wem
RIFF WAVE 2 channels 44100 Hz 368432 bps
6023303 samples
- 2 byte packet headers, no granule
- stripped setup header
- external codebooks (packed_codebooks.bin)
- modified Vorbis packets
Output: 642633853.ogg
Done!
```

but VLC player could still not play it, even with the K-Lite codec pack installed.

### Sound effects (SFX)

The sound effects are stored in the same directory and have two different file extensions: BNK and UPK.

The BNK file format is documented in the [Xentax Wiki](http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/Wwise_SoundBank_(*.bnk)). A BNK file can contain many sounds. The file is easier to identify in this case, since it contains Neo Tokio in the name: `SFX_Amb_NeoTokyo.bnk`. As the name suggests, this is more about the ambient sounds, so I don't expect your goal sound to be in there.

You can use [BNK extract](https://github.com/eXpl0it3r/bnkextr/releases/download/1.1/bnkextr.exe) to get the WEM files out of it, then use ww2ogg as mentioned before. Same result here: I could not play the files.

The other file is `NeoTokio_SFX.upk`. UPK is a file format of the Unreal engine. You can get an [unpacker on Gildor](http://www.gildor.org/downloads) ([Direct Download](http://www.gildor.org/down/41/umodel/extract.zip)).

Unfortunately that extractor fails on my machine as well, which makes me think that the files are encrypted or obfuscated.

Comment: Very interesting and great write-up!

Answer (score 2):

Well I've been searching around for it, and I've maybe found something. It's from a complete soundtrack I've found, and it's called Neon Glow Medley.

--- 2:29:38 - Neon Glow Medley.

Hope this helps ;)